# Problem: register_shutdown_function doesn't start

Tags: php

My part code :

```
  function onDie(){
        $filename= 'statistic.txt';
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'a+') or die('cannot access file statistic.txt');
        fwrite($handle, 'shutdown: ' . mt_rand(1, 100) . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    register_shutdown_function('onDie');

    //onDie();
    echo '1';
    die('FAtal error ');
```

Function onDie didn't run becouse file statistic.txt is empty
What's problem here ? Help please

Comment: According to the docs - `Registers a callback to be executed after script execution finishes or exit() is called.`. If you `die` the script, it's not finishing execution, or exiting.

Comment: @fubar The manual says that `die()` is equivalent to `exit()`.

Comment: @Barmar - good call. I hadn't ever read that before.